# using std::remove_reference to get an element iterator of STL container

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm experimenting with std::remove_reference. For example, I can extract an element type an array but how do I get remove_reference to work with STL containers? For example, I want to return an iterator to an element of a vector using remove_reference below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::begin;
using std::end;
using std::remove_reference;

template<typename T> 
auto my_end(T& c) -> typename remove_reference<decltype(&c[0])>::type
{
    return end(c)-1; //compile error when myend<vector> is instantiated
}

int main()
{
    int ia[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10};
    vector<int> v(begin(ia), end(ia));

    auto my_back1 = *my_end(ia);
    cout << my_back1 << endl; //prints 10

    auto my_back2 = *my_end(v);
    cout << my_back2 << endl; //should print 10
}
```

The compiler error when `my_end<vector>` is instantiated is:

```
cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'int *'
```

Comment: `decltype(&c[0])` doesn't look right

Comment: Why not just `typename T::iterator`? Or `decltype(c.begin())` if you really must.

Comment: @KerrekSB Or `decltype(end(c)-1)` if he really really must.

Comment: `typename remove_reference<decltype(*begin(c))>::type` might be useful for something.  But in most cases I would prefer `typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(begin(c))>::value_type` instead.

Comment: @aschepler those are different; they would be values, he's apparently trying to return an iterator.

Comment: And by values, I mean the value type of the container.

Comment: Well, the whole thing looks like one massive XY problem anyway...

Comment: I know.  "might be useful for something" which is not exactly what this program is trying to do.

Comment: @KerrekSB can't use `typename T::iterator` not `decltype(c.begin())` for an array but `decltype(begin(c))` is good.

Comment: @user1626720: Yeah, good point. I'd go with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the type returned by `std::vector<T>::operator[]` ? It is a `T&`.  So, the result of `decltype(&c[0])` is `T*`.

But what is the type of `end(c)-1`? It is an iterator.

If you want to return an iterator, use `decltype(end(c))` or something similar.

---

Note that if you just want a reference to the last element, you can just use (or wrap):

```
ia.back();
```

and if you want an iterator (for some reason), but don't care about the *direction*:

```
ia.rbegin();
```

which will also de-reference to the last entry.

Your `my_end` is also unsafe if the container is empty ... but of course I'm not sure how you plan to use it.

Answer (score 4):

What's the purpose of `remove_reference` here? `std::vector<T>::end()` yields an iterator, whereas `&c[0]` yields a pointer to an element.

Define what you are expecting `my_end()` to return, and then we can help you solve the problem.

If all you want is to return an iterator, then declare it like this:

```
auto my_end(T& c) -> decltype(begin(c)) { }
```

But then again, you would like to experiment with `remove_reference`, right...?

Comment: I know the code looks useless (it is) but its just a toy example of `remove_reference` It looks more useful if I pass an iterator into my_end(). eg: `template<typename T> 
auto my_end(T It) -> typename remove_reference<decltype(It)>::type
{
    return It-1; 
}

int main()
{
    int ia[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10};
    vector<int> v(begin(ia), end(ia));

    auto my_back1 = my_end(end(ia));
    cout << *my_back1 << endl; //prints 10

    auto my_back2 = my_end(end(v));
    cout << *my_back2 << endl; //should print 10
}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help folks. The code looks lame inline in my comment below so here it is again. This time `remove_reference` is useful to deduce the return type if for example I need to pass an iterator. (Okay so its not exactly that useful....)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::begin;
using std::end;
using std::remove_reference;

template<typename T> 
auto my_end(T It) -> typename remove_reference<decltype(It)>::type
{
    return It-1; 
}

int main()
{
    int ia[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10};
    vector<int> v(begin(ia), end(ia));

    auto my_back1 = my_end(end(ia));
    cout << *my_back1 << endl; //prints 10

    auto my_back2 = my_end(end(v));
    cout << *my_back2 << endl; //should print 10
}
```

Comment: Can anyone please comment on how to work around using `remove_reference()` to deduce the return type here?